# UIbutton change color after tap

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, ios7

I have a `UIButton` ,that has a preset text font and color, I need that to change immediately on  tapping tap button.

I try:

```
- (IBAction)tapAction : (id)sender 
{
    // determine button from tag ..
   [crtBtn setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   [crtBtn setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [crtBtn setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateApplication];
   [crtBtn setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];    
   [crtBtn setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: are you talking about title color or button BG color.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
 - (IBAction)tapAction : (id)sender 
    {  
    [sender setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateNormal]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you don't set IBOutlet for you button (with crtBtn).

```
- (IBAction)tapAction : (id)sender 
{
   [crtBtn setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// or 
   [sender setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateNormal]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
-(IBAction)tapAction: (UIButton *)sender 

{

 [crtBtn setTitleColor:self.selectedTextColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```